# Individual controls of a list view row gets affected on working with other individual control in another list view

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm developing an android application for our music school. I have designed a layout with list view, each list view showing the details of the song such as Movie Poster, Movie Name, Song Name, Year Released, Song Price, Play/Stop, View Sample, Add To/Remove From Cart image views.

Screenshot of the layout is shown below

![Layout screen showing the list of songs][1]

Now I want the user to hear the mp3 version of the song on clicking the Play button. When the song is being played, I would like to change the Play image to Stop image and provide the user with the functionality to stop the song.

Below is the layout file code that holds the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8AE9F"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/aboutComposer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/msv_songs"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/cart_total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pay_now" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMSVSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:focusable="false" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the layout code that specifies how each song detail are displayed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvViewSample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="75sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAddCart"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_to_cart"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView"
        android:src="@drawable/add_to_cart"
        android:tag = "@string/add_to_cart" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPlay"
        android:src="@drawable/view_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPlay"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play_mp3"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am storing the details of each song as a class object. Below is the code of Song.class

```
package com.srindroid.indianmusicsheets;
import java.io.File;

public class Song {

    private int filmImageID;    
    private String movieName;
    private String songName;
    private String yearReleased;
    private int songPrice;
    private int mp3File;

    public Song(int filmImageID, String movieName, String songName,
            String yearReleased, int songPrice, int mp3File) {
        super();
        this.filmImageID = filmImageID;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.songName = songName;
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
        this.songPrice = songPrice;
        this.mp3File = mp3File;

    }
    public int getFilmImageID() {
        return filmImageID;
    }
    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }
    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }
    public String getYearReleased() {
        return yearReleased;
    }
    public int getSongPrice() {
        return songPrice;
    }
    public int getmp3File() {
        return mp3File;
    }
    public void setFilmImageID(int filmImageID) {
        this.filmImageID = filmImageID;
    }
    public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }
    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }
    public void setYearReleased(String yearReleased) {
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
    }   
    public void setSongPrice(int songPrice) {
        this.songPrice = songPrice;
    }    
}
```

Below is the java code to create each row for the list view

```
public class MsvSongs extends Activity {

    int cart_total;
    public MediaPlayer mp3Player=null;  
    private ArrayList<Song> msvSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    ListView songs;

    @Override   
    protected void onStop(){
        if(mp3Player!=null && mp3Player.isPlaying()){
            mp3Player.stop();
            mp3Player.release();
            mp3Player=null;
        }       
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        if(mp3Player!=null && mp3Player.isPlaying()){
            mp3Player.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        if(mp3Player!=null){
            mp3Player.start();
        }
        super.onResume();
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.msv_music_sheets);
        populateSongsList();
        populateSongsListView();
    }



    private void populateSongsList() {
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_ayirathil_oruvan,"Ayirathil Oruvan","Adho Andha Paravai Pola","1965",150,R.raw.msv_adho_andha_paravai_pola_ao));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_karuppu_panam,"Karuppu Panam","Aadavaralaam","1964",150,R.raw.msv_aadavaralaam_kp));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_paalum_pazhamum,"Paalum Paazhamum","Aalayamaniyin Oosai","1961",150,R.raw.msv_aalayamaniyin_oosai_pp));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_paava_mannippu,"Paava Mannipu","Athaan Ennathan","1961",150,R.raw.msv_athaan_ennathaan_pm));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_periya_idhuthu_pen,"Periya Idhuthu Pen","Andru Vandhadhadhum Adhey Nila","1963",175,R.raw.msv_andru_vandhadhum_adhey_nila_pip));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_puthiya_paravai,"Pudhiya Paravai","Enge Nimmadhi","1964",250,R.raw.msv_enge_nimmadhi_pparavai));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_server_sundaram,"Server Sundaram","Avalukku Enna Azhagiya Mugam","1964",150,R.raw.msv_avalukkenna_azhagiamugham_ss));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_panam_padaithavan,"Panam Padaithavan","Kan Pona Pookiley","1965",175,R.raw.msv_kan_pona_pokkile_pp));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.msv_vasantha_maligai,"Vasantha Maligai","Mayakkam Enna","1972",120,R.raw.msv_mayakkam_yenna_vm));
    }

    private void populateSongsListView() {
        songs=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMSVSongs);
        BaseAdapter msvAdapter = new MsvSongsAdapter(MsvSongs.this, msvSongs);
        songs.setAdapter(msvAdapter);       
    }   

    public class MsvSongsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private List<Song> songs;

        public MsvSongsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> msvSongs){
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            songs = msvSongs;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return songs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return songs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_view, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.filmPoster = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgFilmPoster);
                holder.filmName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvFilmName);
                holder.songName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
                holder.yearReleased = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvYearReleased);
                holder.songPrice = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                holder.mp3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                view = convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            }

            Song currentSong = songs.get(position);
            holder.filmPoster.setImageResource(currentSong.getFilmImageID());
            holder.filmName.setText(currentSong.getMovieName());
            holder.songName.setText(currentSong.getSongName());
            holder.yearReleased.setText(currentSong.getYearReleased());
            holder.songPrice.setText("Rs. "+currentSong.getSongPrice());

            holder.mp3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String contentDesc = (String) holder.mp3.getContentDescription();
                    if (contentDesc.contains("Play")) {
                        if (mp3Player != null && mp3Player.isPlaying()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Stop the previous song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(MsvSongs.this, songs.get(position).getmp3File());
                            mp3Player.start();
                            ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                            ((ImageView)v).setContentDescription("Stop MP3");
                        }
                    } else {
                        mp3Player.pause();
                        mp3Player.stop();
                        mp3Player.release();
                        mp3Player = null;
                        ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        ((ImageView)v).setContentDescription("Play MP3");
                    }

                }
            });         

            return view;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            public ImageView filmPoster, mp3;
            public TextView filmName, songName, yearReleased, songPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem I face here is when I click the Play button of first song in the list view, it plays the appropriate mp3 file and changes the Play icon to Stop icon as expected. See screenshot below

![enter image description here][2]

But it also changes the Play icon to Stop icon of other song in the list as well. See screenshot below

![enter image description here][3]

Could you please let me know what is causing this issue?

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is with the `OnClickListener` and the `ViewHolder`.  The `getView()` method will recycle/reuse views.  Meaning a `View` at position 2 may later end up being reused for position 6.  That means your click listener for position 2 is now suddenly changing the `View` at position 6.

Splice out your `OnClickListener` as it's on separate nested class and don't make `ViewHolder` final. Then when you instantiate the `OnClickListener` pass along the `ViewHolder` and the `Song`.  It's easier to show in code, so here's a quick example:

```
private class OnSongClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private WeakReference<ViewHolder> mViewHolder;
    private Song mSong;

    public OnSongClickListener(ViewHolder vh, Song song) {
        mViewHolder = new WeakReference<ViewHolder>(vh);
        mSong = song;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewHolder vh = mViewHolder.get();
        if (vh == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Do your click logic here
    }
}
```

You'll also need your `getView()` method to ensure the View's are reset according to their current playback status.  For example:

```
Song currentSong = songs.get(position);
holder.filmPoster.setImageResource(currentSong.getFilmImageID());
holder.filmName.setText(currentSong.getMovieName());
holder.songName.setText(currentSong.getSongName());
holder.yearReleased.setText(currentSong.getYearReleased());
holder.songPrice.setText("Rs. "+currentSong.getSongPrice());
holder.mp3.setOnClickListener(new OnSongClickListener(holder,currentSong));

if (currentSong is playing) {  //You'll need a way to determine this
    holder.mp3.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    holder.mp3.setContentDescription("Play MP3");
} else {
    holder.mp3.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    holder.mp3.setContentDescription("Stop MP3");
}

return view;
```

Comment: Hi Jay Sover, Thanks for your response. I changed the code as below

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me now. I added a Boolean variable in my Song class and setting it to true when the song is being played.

Comment: Hi Jay Sover, How do I accept your answer? Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi Jay Sover, I have put a new question for Android In-App Billing. Can you please help me with that?